# I don't think this question should be put on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84889/do-loading-screens-positioned-above-site-content-harm-seo) was put on hold because **it's specific to one website**. I don't think the question is specific to just ONE site, but it applies to ALL sites that display a loading screen with `height: 100%;` which covers all content and afterwards is hidden from JavaScript.

I deleted a short paragraph within the question that referred to my *specific* website, but kept the code snippets as they help clarify what I'm asking.

Moreover, there are other SO users that find my question worth answering.

LATER EDIT: I deleted the link to my website, and I see NO OTHER QUESTIONS ON SO REFERRING TO LOADING SCREENS.

Answer (score 3):

This question should remain closed for two reasons:

1. In it's current form it links to the current page for review. That makes it specific for one website which is off-topic here. Removing it would solve that problem as you did include the code in your question.
2. But even if that link is removed it would then be a duplicate of [several similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com%20seo%20hidden%20content&oq=site%3Aw&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i58j69i59l3.3415j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). There isn't anything new being asked in this question to warrant reopening it.

Comment: Okay, so I deleted the website link and there is NO question related to LOADING SCREENS. Can I have my question open now? :)

Comment: Just because it is a loading screen doesn't make it fundamentally different than the other questions we already have. The *concept* is the same even if the specific implementation is different.